# Code works logically on macOS but not on Ubuntu 16.04.5

Tags: c, linux, macos, memory-management

I have a task to write the function:

`int read_palindrome(); // input comes from stdin`

which will read one line from standard input and returns 1 if the line is a palindrome and 0 otherwise. A line is terminated by the newline character (’\n’) and the does not include the newline.

There are requirements to be met:

There is no assumption about the length of the input. 
You are also not allowed to read the input twice, e.g. read the input, forget you read the input but remember the length, read the input again. which results in the input being read twice.

You are also not allowed to create a very large buffer to store the input reasoning that the input line might be expected to be smaller than a very large buffer. 
The reason for this restriction is that we will consider the memory usage of the program.

The task is to come out with a correct program with the best CPU time and memory usage.

The following is my attempt.

file1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int read_palindrome();

int main() 
{
    if (read_palindrome()) printf("input is a palindrome");
    else printf("input is not a palindrome");
    return 0;
}
```

file2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int check_palindrome2(char *, int);

int read_palindrome() {
    unsigned int len_max = 128;
    unsigned int current_size = 0;
    char *pStr = malloc(len_max); 
    current_size = len_max;
    int i = 0;
    char c;
    if (pStr != NULL) {
        while (( c = getchar() ) != '\n') { 
            pStr[i] = (char)c;
            i++;
            if(i == current_size) {
                current_size += len_max; 
                char *tmp = realloc(pStr, current_size);
                if (tmp == NULL) {
                    free(pStr);
                    return 2;
                }
                pStr = tmp;

            }
        }

        pStr[i] = '\0';
        free(pStr);

    }
    return check_palindrome2(pStr,i);
}   


int check_palindrome2(char *s, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (s[i]!= s[length-i-1]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

After copying the file onto both machines, running the appropriate compilation commands on both my MacOS and Ubuntu, and feeding a known palindrome of 121.

```
gcc -c file1.c
gcc -c file2.c
gcc -o output file1.c file2.c
./output
```

The code prints `input is a palindrome` on MacOS but `input is not a palindrome` on Ubuntu.Can anyone tell me if there's anything wrong with my code, or there should be something I should be doing differently across the different OS.

Comment: Your program frees `pStr` and then proceeds accessing it. This is undefined behaviour. Use `valgrind` or address sanitizer to catch such errors.

Comment: sorry which particular free(pStr) are you referring to?

Comment: There are two of those. Is it too complicated to look at both?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to this dynamic allocation concept. I take it that you are referring to the one after inserting end of string. Would removing that particular free resolve the situation?

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: I don't have access to a LINUX machine now, it still works on my Mac so I can't validate it by trying

Comment: You return 2 in error case if `realloc` fails. But you don't return an error value if first `alloc` fails. You also call your `check_palindrom` function in that case which will return 1. Both error cases will result in a message that you have a palindrome. Also: 128 bytes might be considered a "very large block of memory" for an input like "121"

Comment: Removing the `free` will solve that specific bug but instead cause a memory leak. You just need to free after dereferencin the pointer for the last time.

Comment: You may want to learn how to use address sanitizer and other sanitizer libraries. Valgrind should also work under Mac OS (be sure to check out the latest version).

Comment: @Gerhardh I was just testing out my code so I did a simple test, didn't care about efficiency back then when I was trying to figure out why it doesnt work on LINUX.

Comment: and are you implying that free should not be in the branch but instead be outside right before the return value?

Comment: regarding: `char c;
    if (pStr != NULL) {
        while (( c = getchar() ) != '\n') { `  The function: `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char` and the `int` is needed because `getchar()` can return `EOF (which the `while()` statement should also be checking for.)

Comment: this statement: `if (s[i]!= s[length-i-1]) {` checks for a palindrome twice.  Suggest adding a check to exit the loop when the offsets are equal or the left offset is greater than the right offset

Comment: OT: immediately after the call to `malloc()` and after the call to `realloc()` is when the check for NULL should be made and if NULL then call `perror( "your error message" );` which will output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: OT: when compiling, always enable the warnings then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc` at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note other compilers use different options to produce the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have inconsistent error handling.
In one case you return 2, in another you indirectly return 1. This should be changed:

I will use negative values for errors:

```
int read_palindrome()
{
    unsigned int len_max = 128;
    unsigned int current_size = 0;
    char *pStr = malloc(len_max); 
    current_size = len_max;
    int i = 0;
    char c;
    if (pStr == NULL)
        return -1;

    while (( c = getchar() ) != '\n') { 
        pStr[i] = (char)c;
        i++;
        if(i == current_size) {
            current_size += len_max; 
            char *tmp = realloc(pStr, current_size);
            if (tmp == NULL) {
                free(pStr);
                return -1;
            }
            pStr = tmp;
        }
    }

    pStr[i] = '\0';
    free(pStr);
    return check_palindrome2(pStr,i);  // If pStr==NULL we do not reach this line.
}
```

Now you have -1 returned in any error case and you do not use `pStr` if it is `NULL`.

Let's address the "use after free" problem:

```
    free(pStr);
    return check_palindrome2(pStr,i);
```

Accessing `pStr` after freeing it is illegal. Rearrange the function calls.

```
    int retval = check_palindrome2(pStr,i);
    free(pStr);
    return retval;
```

In addition to these changes you need to handle the return value of this function properly:

```
int main() 
{
    int pali = read_palindrome();

    if (pali < 0)
        printf("An error occured.\n");
    else if (pali) 
        printf("Input is a palindrome\n");
    else 
        printf("Input is no palindrome\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Finally lets speed up your palindrome detection a bit:

```
int check_palindrome2(char *s, int length) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)  // only walk up to the middle.
    {
        if (s[i] != s[length-i-1])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

If `s[1] == s[9]` is true then `s[9] == s[1]` will also be true. No need to check twice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, am I correct to conclude that LINUX is more strict as compared to macOS? While some code seems to work on macOS consistently, they are not necessarily working on LINUX.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Accessing that memory location is simply undefined behaviour. Anything can happen. This includes that it may simply seem to "work as expected".